# Toggling the menu programmatically if I have more than one menu?

Tags: angular, angular2-material

If I am having 2 menu component in my template like below

```
<button md-icon-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
    <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
  <button md-menu-item>Refresh</button>
  <button md-menu-item>Settings</button>
  <button md-menu-item>Help</button>
  <button md-menu-item disabled>Sign Out</button>
</md-menu>

<button md-icon-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu1">
    <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
</button>
<md-menu #menu1="mdMenu">
  <button md-menu-item>Refresh</button>
  <button md-menu-item>Settings</button>
  <button md-menu-item>Help</button>
  <button md-menu-item disabled>Sign Out</button>
</md-menu>
```

How to programatically toggle the second menu component?.
Normally @ViewChild(MdMenuTrigger) we can use the following if I have only one menu component in template. Is there any way by specifying the component name in the @ViewChild to find out the nth menu component and open the menu programatically?

Answer (score 4):

first, you need to hook **AfterViewInit** to your component

`class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {`

then you can do that by using **@ViewChildren**

```
@ViewChildren(MdMenuTrigger) triggers: QueryList<MdMenuTrigger>; 
// use ViewChildren to get a list of menu element

ngAfterViewInit() {

  // inside ngAfterViewInit lifecycle
  // you get the triggers

  this.triggers.forEach((item)=>{
    item.openMenu();
  });

}
```

Comment: You can access the particular menu using name [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu2" #trial="mdMenuTrigger". please refer the issue in Agnualar material https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2421

Comment: Can anybody please explain, what does the row `#trial="mdMenuTrigger"` means?